# Why does this error occur? Error when sending a transaction: cannot estimate gas; transaction may fail or may require manual gas limit?

Tags: nodejs

There is enough balance, the network is also working correctly, the keys are also correct, the gas has been increased, but the error remains.

```
const ethers = require("ethers");

const networkRPC = 'https://eth-sepolia.g.alchemy.com/v2/UfPvcFpj2bEwwTF4OXlEVP4atqGHfgUk';
const senderPrivateKey = '0xa0278f908d619f8967aa252b80679ca5ff2e85b31103dd53741c39780f6717a3';
const recipientAddress = '0xa014da1d3baC8799E78EE5cF87ff2bb105491d28';
const tokenAddress = '0x91B25A65b295F0405552A4bbB77879ab5e38166c';
const amountToSend = "0.000001"; // Указывайте в токенах, которые будут конвертированы в Wei

const provider = new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider(networkRPC);
const senderWallet = new ethers.Wallet(senderPrivateKey, provider);

const tokenABI = [
    "function balanceOf(address owner) view returns (uint256)",
    "function transfer(address to, uint amount) returns (bool)"
];

const tokenContract = new ethers.Contract(tokenAddress, tokenABI, senderWallet);

async function sendSWAN() {
    try {
        const amountInWei = ethers.utils.parseUnits(amountToSend, 18);

        // Проверка баланса перед отправкой
        const senderBalance = await tokenContract.balanceOf(senderWallet.address);
        if (senderBalance.lt(amountInWei)) {
            console.error("Недостаточно средств для отправки");
            return;
        }

        // Фиксированные значения газа и цены газа
        const gasLimit = ethers.BigNumber.from("2100000");
        const gasPrice = ethers.BigNumber.from("8000000000");

        // Отправка транзакции
        const transaction = await tokenContract.transfer(recipientAddress, amountInWei, {
            gasLimit: gasLimit,
            gasPrice: gasPrice
        });

        console.log(`Транзакция отправлена: ${transaction.hash}`);
        const receipt = await transaction.wait();
        console.log(`Транзакция успешно выполнена в блоке ${receipt.blockNumber}`);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(`Ошибка при отправке транзакции: ${error.message}`);
    }
}

sendSWAN().catch(console.error);
```

Comment: The token address that you're using [0x91B25A65b295F0405552A4bbB77879ab5e38166c](https://sepolia.etherscan.io/address/0x91B25A65b295F0405552A4bbB77879ab5e38166c) is not an **ERC20** token, instead it's an **ERC721** token (i.e., an NFT). Therefore, the ABI in `tokenABI` value that you're using, is not applicable for this, so you cannot call the corresponding `balanceOf()` and `transfer()` functions for this token.